# Stop timer of previous instances inside the constructor?

Tags: c#, timer

I have an object `foo` with a timer inside which I would like to stop once I reassign `foo`. To do that, right now I do the following

```
var foo=new MyClass();

//Do stuff....

if (foo!=null){foo.timer.stop();}

foo=new MyClass();
```

Is there a way I could add this kind of logic inside MyClass constructor, or a more elegant/easier way to do this?

```
 public class MyClass
        {
            public DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            public MyClass()
            {
                timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);
                timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
            }
            private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("I tick!!");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [Finalizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/destructors), in this case it would look like:

```
~MyClass {
    timer.stop();
}
```

Comment: I tried, but I think it does not dispose the object until the GC wants to which may not be immediately

Comment: You could implement IDisposable, and then explicitly call .dispose

Comment: yes, I may try. The thing is that I usually hear in forums that it is not a good idea to force the GC to dispose objects. In the other hand, I would still have to dispose the object right before reassigning, which is basically what I am doing right now

Comment: True, if you're not willing to wait for the GC to come around and collect, I don't think what you're asking is possible without a dispose call. However, as far as I know, there is no issue with explicitly calling dispose on objects.

Comment: What you've described is a Timer that is SHARED across all instances.  Make the Timer [static](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static).  Now you can put the code that checks for null and stops the Timer in the Constructor.

Comment: yes, that is an interesting idea that I think would work for my problem. However, that will also force different instances of the class (like ```MyClass foo1,foo2```) to be sharing the same tick event.

Comment: You could potentially have a static list of KeyValuePairs<string, timer>, which you assign the name of the variable that's holding the current object reference as the key, with the timer as the value. Pass the name of the variable in the object constructor and restart the timer if it already exists. This does have the limitation of not being able to have two variables of the same name containing instances of that class though, unless you find another way to uniquely identify them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put the logic in the MyClass constructor, you can:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();

    public MyClass()
    {
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);
        timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
    }
    
    public MyClass(MyClass oldFoo) : MyClass()
    {
        oldFoo?.StopTimer();
    }
    
    public void StopTimer()
    {
        timer.Stop();
    }
    
    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I tick!!");
    }
}
```

And the reassignment code becomes

```
var foo = new MyClass();

//Do stuff....

foo = new MyClass(foo);
```

But I wonder whether the responsibility for stopping al old timer should really lie with a newly created instance of MyClass. From a logical point of view, it seems like the piece of code that created the object, then did something with it, should also be responsible for stopping the timer of the object it just created. So I might be inclined to go with your original solution.